# Two column responsive website issue

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

I am trying to convert an existing site into responsive however there is one thing I'm struggling with here:

http://www.brandonsuffolk.com

When you resize the window I want the right column to squash the left one, however at the moment it drops underneath (however once the screen hits the other left div it will change).

When I do it with single divs it works, however as soon as I add a new div inside it, it won't work properly.

Here is the relevant CSS:

```
.MainOuter {
    float: left;
    width: 100%;
}
.MainWrapper {
    max-width: 980px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: auto;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: auto;
    padding-top: 0px;
    padding-right: 10px;
    padding-bottom: 0px;
    padding-left: 10px;
}
.ColumnRight {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 20px;
    float: right;
    width: 290px;
    padding: 0px;;
}
.ColumnLeft {
    margin-top: 20px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
    margin-left: 0px;
    float: left;
    width: auto;
    max-width: 670px;
    padding: 0px;
}
```

Comment: By squash you meen by keeping it at a proportion of 7/3?

Comment: Not exactly those proportions no. As soon as the divs meet, I want the left one to change and fill the gap with the right one set at 300px. Everything else I can sort out after getting this problem solved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming I understood, and you want the right-side column to maintain the fixed width, you'll need to use `position:absolute` with a `left` and `right` value, and `width` set to `auto`. This gives you a fixed side and a side that takes the rest of the screen.

Wanting it to only apply after they touch though, is where you'll have to use a media query. Set the media query to apply only when the screen is lower than 1000px, which will tell the left column to change there and become flexible.

**EDIT**

Try adding this CSS to your site's CSS file, at the end. Additionally I've updated the Fiddle to show how that it works. You might have to tweak the numbers a little, but it'll do what you need.

[**Example Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/JAr6X/1/)

```
@media screen and (max-width: 1000px) {

    .ColumnLeft {
        position: absolute;
        left: 20px;
        right: 320px;
        width:auto;
    }

}
```

Comment: That does appear to work however you say if I want it only to happen when they meet then that is how it's done. On my proper site they are already next to each other, does that make a difference?

Comment: With this, they are floated apart, and fixed width, when the screen is wide enough that there is space between. When the screen is small enough that they'd touch, then the left becomes flexible.

Comment: I have now edited my original question to show the proper website and CSS. Hopefully you can then see what I'm trying to do.

Comment: I understand now. I'll update the Fiddle and my answer.

Comment: Updated, please take a look and see if that will solve your issue. A note, you'll also need to use a query (you can use the same one) to change over the nav bar on top.

Comment: Thank you, with a bit of tweaking the values that has worked. However, because it using absolute positioning it now goes over the top of the bottom part of the site as it gets thinner.

Comment: Glad to help. Another option is to use calc(). It'll do the same thing without absolute positioning, but you'll lose older browser compatibility. You'd do something like `width:calc(100%-320px)`.

Answer (score 2):

I'm afraid you're fighting the normal process of responsiveness. responsiveness is supposed to do just what it's doing. If you don't want it to drop under, find the @media for this element and change it to:

```
@media (min-width:0px) {
    width:50%;
}
```

This may help

Answer (score 1):

May this is what you mean with "squash" ?

http://jsfiddle.net/7QVVz/

CSS

```
.wrap {
   display: table;
   width: 100%;
}

.left {
   display: table-cell;
   border: 1px solid green;
   width: 350px;
   max-width: 350px;
}

.right {
   display: table-cell;
   border: 1px solid red;
}

.right > .text {
   width: 200px;
   float: right;
   border: 1px solid yellow;
}
```

HTML

```
<div class="wrap">
   <div class="left">LEFT</div>
   <div class="right">
      <div class="text">RIGHT TEXT</div>
   </div>
</div>
```